How can I attach a mullion to a laminated cabinet door edge?
I want to remove center stile to easily access big items in the cabinet. Once I remove the stile, I know I would have to attach the narrow strip of wood onto one of the doors inner side to cover the gap when doors are closed.
As you can see in the picture my cabinet doors are laminated, not solid wood. What options do I have to attach the wooden strip if I don't want to screw it? My fear is that screwing would damage laminate and crack it. If it was solid wood, I would have screwed it.
Would some kind of super glue work?


Check the backside of the stile to make sure it is not adding support for the shelves.  Pilot holes or use glue/adhesive to add to the doors.

Depending on overlap one may need more structural support since you will end up stressing it more than you think. Or at least I did in a similar situation. Sistering a board on the back of the cabinet door and adding some metal bits fixed it.

Those shelves are very thin.  I'm betting there are shelf supports on the back of the piece you want to remove, and the shelves will sag without that support.

The "stile" (actually face frame, not a stile) is likely structural to the cabinet, so expect that to sag (at least) or fall apart.
As noted in a comment, check for shelf supports on the back of it as well.

This would be a great use case for a good double-sided foam tape (or mounting squares). The foam allows better contact than you'd get with a plain tape and the flexibility to handle impacts. It'll also create a gap between the mullion and the other door so they don't collide.
If you use tape labeled "permanent" it'll hold like mad. Look for a fairly thin foam to minimize the gap, and keep it back from the door edge a bit so it doesn't show.
